# Angular 2 animations

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-animations

Is it possible to animate elements on Angular 2 like on jQuery? For example, I want div containing sub-elements to expand/shrink when clicked. Does Angular 2 provide directives for this, or do I have to call jQuery inside Angular event handlers ?

Comment: Just toggle a class and animate via CSS.

Comment: This sounds more easy than it is. Seems like CSS only allows to animate height with absolute value. I tried something like @keyframes expand { from {height: 0px;} to {height: auto;}} but it didn't work. I'm using Bootstrap btw.

Comment: For variable height elements, many people have been animating the `max-height` property. The only reason I'm recommending it is because it doesn't litter your angular code with jQuery logic and it doesn't mix your presentation logic with your interaction logic.

Comment: I found an easier solution, just use data-toggle="collapse" element attribute of bootstrap library. I have no idea how it does it's magic, but it's easy solution to make dropdown panels

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html

Remember to use the polyfills for older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Just use bootstrap accordion . Here is a link to it
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/